# Is there a way to implement an if-else condition that is threadsafe/ atomic in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, thread-safety, atomic

Let's take for example:

```
 public class XYZ{
    private AtomicInteger var1;
    private int const_val;

    // these all attributes are initialized with a constructor, when an instance of the class is called.

    // my focus is on this method, to make this thread-safe
    public boolean isPossible(){
        if(var1 < const_val){
            var1.incrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to make this (entire "if-else" snippet) thread-safe/atomic if I cannot use the locking mechanism (in java)?

I read something on the line of AtomicIntegers, and reading something with AtomicBooleans, can I use these to make this snippet thread-safe?

Comment: Depends does condition and update a variable involve the same variable?

Comment: Maybe something alongside java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean for the condition, and similar for your "update_a_variable", for instance, if "update_a_variable" is a long, to use AtomicLong

Comment: If you do not have access to `synchronized` and `volatile` (and anything that is based on them) you could try creating a temp file and the thread that manages to create the file has the lock until the it deletes the file again - to acquire the lock you have to repeatedly try to create the file until the thread succeeds.

Comment: You cannot make it thread safe without some kind of locking, if you say that you want locking without locking you are out of options.

Comment: @luk2302 sorry for not adding mu details have added a real snippet now. I am inclined to not use the locks and use something with AtomicInteger and AtomicBoolean, to do the thread-safe work.

Comment: @dreamcrash have updated, the question, please have a look and suggest some way!

Comment: @SilentFlame Is this a homework or a job interview question? why you cannot use synchronized?

Comment: @dreamcrash Naah, neither of those, it's just I was working on something with a friend and we got to think, is there a way to do this thread-safe without a lock, read something on AtomicInteger and AtomicBoolean and thought this community might have an idea on this.

Comment: @SilentFlame Have a look at pveentjer answer I think is exactly what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
public boolean isPossible(){
    for(;;){
        int current = var1.get();
        if(current>=max){
            return false;
        }
        
        if(var1.compareAndSet(current, current+1)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Using a loop is the typical to way to implement such logic. So instead of using a lock, you calculate what the next state should be and hope to do an compare and set to set the new value. But it could be that a different thread changed the state, so you need to try again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation nice pattern to know about. I will delete my answer I completely miss the trick of doing while(true) to ensure the same semantic as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enforcing the maximum at writing time, you can increment unconditionally, and enforce the maximum at reading time, like so:

```
public boolean increment(){
    return var1.getAndIncrement() < const_val;
}

public int getVar1() {
    return Math.min(const_val, var1.get());
}
```

That's assuming that all you ever do with this variable is increment it. One issue with this solution is it could eventually lead to overflow. If that's a likely concern, you can switch to AtomicLong.

Comment: Hi, you can have a race condition one threading doing var1.getAndIncrement() while another is doing var1.get() at the same time

Comment: Whether that is a problem depends on what exactly OP is doing after reading. If they have more requirements then they should add them to the question.